# TWO menus with jquery sliding line on hover

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, magicline

i'm trying to make a Jquery menu with a sliding line on hover.
I've found a function known as Magic Line but it works if i apply that to one menu only. 
I need to make two separated menus with the sliding line.
Can anyone show me how to do that?

here is my code.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toccataefiga/2M45j/2/)

`menu #1 is B1, B2, B3.`

`menu #2 is IT / EN`

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that, looking at the magic line function, only one "magic line" can exist. You need to change the code of the function:
1. store magic lines in an array object
2. check array object how many lines exist, then use magic-line+idNr
e.g. `this.append("<li><a id='magic-line"+idNr+"'>&nbsp;</a></li>");`
and anywhere the id used

After that just do this:
`$('.nav_lang').my_magicline();`

Comment: thank you both! now it works. i have a last question. when you resize the page there is a offset between the line and the menu button, until you refresh the page. is there a way to solve that? thank you!

Comment: try using that line again at on resize: $(window).on('resize', function() {jQuery(".nav").my_magicline();}); It might work

Answer (score 0):

Have Fixed your problem, you have not called the magicline function for other menu. If you add this `$(".nav_lang").my_magicline();` it work.

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2M45j/4/)